# Update ActionBar menu depending on navigation destination

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-architecture-navigation

I would like to change the menu items displayed in my `ActionBar` depending on the current destination of my `NavController`. By "change" I mean inflate a specified menu-xml for each destination.

The behavior could be compared to the integrated way the new navigation system changes the `ActionBar` title, depending on the given `android:label` for the destination fragment in the navigation-xml.

So far I setup a basic activity with `ActionBar` and `DrawerLayout` using the new Android navigation. Also I created all necessary XML files and Fragments to navigate between.

```
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...    

    this._drawerLayout = this.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = this.findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
    this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionbar = Objects.requireNonNull( this.getSupportActionBar() );
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

    NavigationView navigationView = this.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(menuItem -> {
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        this._drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        return true;
    });

    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navigation_host);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, this._drawerLayout);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Here I inflate the ActionBar menu that is kept between all destinations.
    // Instead of keeping the same menu between all destinations I want to display different menus depending on the destination fragment.
    this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_items, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this._drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        case R.id.appbar_search:
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I thought about using an individual toolbar in each destination fragment 
but I discarded the idea, because I would lose the transition animation between hamburger icon and back-arrow icon.

Is there any way to achieve this with the new navigation system or in any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to achieve the desired behavior by calling `menu.clear();` before inflating the updated layout. I am still wondering if there is a built-in way to achieve this with the new navigation system.

In the destination Fragment I am using this now:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    menu.clear();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_items_idle, menu);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just tested this. With the current version (2.2.2) of the navigation library, menu items inflated by each fragment will be added and removed as you navigate around.

***But onCreateOptionsMenu is not called by default***! To make things work, you have to sprinkle the magic dust and call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` during initialisation.

Beware, any menu items inflated by the containing activity will always appear alongside the ones from the current fragment, so if you don't want any common menu items, it's probably easiest to not inflate a menu in the Activity.

Side note: in the `Fragment` class, `onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)` is an empty method, so the call to `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)` in your code is a no-op.